# Openshift and evil Git clone

Tags: git, openshift

I've tried to follow the instructions and use "git clone" but it always stops at "compressing 47%", tried two different apps so I'm willing to give up on that one.
I have a ssh key and I can login using it, I also updated my rhc gem and ran out of ideas.

OS: Ubuntu 13.04

Alternatively, are there any browser based editors one could use to edit the files directly on openshift, like Azures Visual Studio online?

Regards

Comment: What repo are you trying to clone?

Comment: I tried git clone ssh://53050...@peo-elwis.rhcloud.com/~/git/peo.git and git clone ssh://53050...@restservice-elwis.rhcloud.com/~/git/restservice.git/

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://c9.io for an online editior.

As for your git clone, it could be a networking issue. Can you clone a repo directly from github or bitbucket without any problems?

Comment: thanks for the hint, not that i dislike VI but some coloring would be nice. Yes, I tried using git against github and it worked nicely

Comment: [Cloud 9 is a fully functioning editor with coloring see here](http://imgur.com/NPJE9K0)

As for your git clone, try appending -vvv to the end and lets see if we can find out why its not progressing.

Comment: But, you cant access your openshift accounts directly from them, right? I appended -vvv and got
Server supports multi_ack_detailed
Server supports side-band-64k
Server supports ofs-delta
Server version is git/1.8.2.1
want 48a915aa83cd784d9f31b1b30b1808b1e7a6559f (HEAD)
want 48a915aa83cd784d9f31b1b30b1808b1e7a6559f (refs/heads/master)
done
remote: Counting objects: 21, done.
remote: Compressing objects:  47% (8/17)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by access... you can develop and push directly to Openshift [check out this video](https://www.openshift.com/videos/developing-in-the-cloud-with-cloud-9-ide-and-openshift). However, If you want to access the Openshift Web-Console you would need to go to openshift.com for that.

also how long did you wait for your git clone to finish? If you have a lot of large files it can take a significant amount of time to complete.

Comment: Sounds great, pushing to openshift is all I need. No, it's just a newly created barebone app, I waited for an hour..